# Postgresql select count with join

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE stores (
stores_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id varchar
);

CREATE TABLE sets (
sets_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
stores_id varchar not null,
owner_id varchar not null,
item_id varchar not null,
);
```

How do I make a request that shows the number of items on the sets in stores?
With selection by owner.

For example:

```
select
stores.*,
count(sets.item_id)
from stores
LEFT OUTER JOIN sets on stores.owner_id = sets.owner_id
where
stores.owner_id = 'e185775fc4f5'
GROUP BY stores.owner_id;
```

Thank you.

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'd need to join on both the store and the owner, then COUNT(DISTINCT item_id)

```
select
st.owner_id, 
st.stores_id, 
count(distinct se.item_id)
  from stores st left join
    sets se
       on st.owner_id = se.owner_id
       and st.stores_id = se.stores_id
           group by st.owner_id, st.stores_id;
```

That will give a table that shows the owner, the store, then the number of items

Comment: Yes, its work! That i was add where st.owner_id = 'e185775fc4f5'

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select st.stores_id, count(se.item_id)
from stores st left join
     sets se
     on st.owner_id = se.owner_id
where st.owner_id = 'e185775fc4f5'
group by st.stores_id;
```

Comment: album_id   | count 
--------------+-------
 3c70f26b3123 |    14
 abad4544b213 |    14
 c51acaf5091a |    14
 e86229e70d84 |    14
(4 rows)
Thus, the same quantity is obtained.